# Can you access methods within a callback in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, methods, anonymous-function, jquery-callback

I'm using optimizely to create an A/B test and I need to be able to call this method to tap into some of the page's functionality.

[EDIT]Because this is pre-existing code on the page and this is an Optimizely test.  I cannot alter the pre-existing JS[/EDIT]

```
$(".some-element").each(function() {
  var val1 = "test";

  function callMeMaybe() {
     console.log("val1 = " + val1);
  }  
});
//need to somehow callMeMaybe out here
```

Is there a way to externally trigger callMeMaybe?

Comment: No. You need to place the definition of `callMeMaybe()` in scope of all places where it will be called. Move it outside of the `each()` block and it will work fine.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the main post.  Its an optimizely test - I cant edit the pre-existing JS code.

Comment: You can't do that.